# What is the action hook for an order that fails on frontend checkout in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks, actions

I am working on a plugin that handles logic for when a user tries to checkout on the frontend and the order fails (e.g., person is using a credit card but it does not have enough balance to meet the cart totals, etc). I can see the order is in fact set as "FAILED" in WooCommerce, because I get the automated email from WC alerting admin of a failed order. I'm spending a lot of time testing out various actions and filters, and hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch specific status change by using this action hook 'woocommerce_order_status_{status}'. It is defined in the [WC_Order class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-order.php).

This is how you define it:

```
/**
 * Executed when the status is changed to failed.
 * @param int $order_id
 * @param \WC_Order $order
 */
function wpdg_9291_woocommerce_order_status_failed( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Do something here
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_failed', 'wpdg_9291_woocommerce_order_status_failed', 15, 2);
```

Comment: seems that hook only allows for one parameter passed in - `$order_id`

Comment: It does accept the second parameter and it's of the type WC_Order. If you look in the class the second parameter is passed as $this - that would be the instance of the current class WC_Order where the actual action is made.

Answer (score 0):

When customer returns from a gateway without paying, it falls on order received *(thankyou)* page with 2 possible status: `failed` or `pending`, and there is 2 possible action hooks:

- `woocommerce_thankyou_{$order_payment_method}` *(composite hook with `$order_id` available argument)*
- `woocommerce_thankyou` *(with `$order_id` available argument)*

You can target that case with the following example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_action_callback', 10, 1 );
function thankyou_action_callback( $order_id ) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if( in_array( $order->get_status(), ['failed','pending'] ) ) {
        // Your code comes here
    }
}
```